# Combinatorics: several problems

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have several questions related to combinatorics. I am not a mathematician, and only understand the basics of $n \choose k$ (and commonly use Wolfram Alpha to solve such problems), maybe you can take this into account when answering. Thank you!

1) Imagine a disorder has 9 symptoms, and 5 are required for a diagnosis: that leads to 9 choose 5 (unordered, no repeats) symptom profiles that qualify for a diagnosis, correct?

2) Now imagine that these 9 symptoms are on 2 lists: list A has 2 symptoms, list B 7 symptoms. For a diagnosis, at least 1 symptom of list A, and at least 4 symptoms of list B have to be present. How many symptom profiles are there that qualify for the diagnosis?

3) It gets more complex. Symptom 2 is "diminished interest or pleasure". Interest and pleasure are different things, and I want to take that into account. So a person could have symptom 1, symptom 2a, symptom 2b, symptom 3, and so forth. That increases the number of possible symptom profiles: profile 2a 4 6 7 9 is distinct from 2b 4 6 7 9. How do I calculate that?

4) In fact, 6 of the 9 symptoms encompass 2 features (symptoms 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8). Unfortunately, I cannot simply increases the number of symptoms to make the calculation, because for example 1 4a 4b 6 7 would not qualify as symptom profile. Although there are 5 different symptoms present, 1 of the first list, 4 of the second list, 4a and 4b are handled as being the same symptom in the manual, and so this would not qualify. Neither would 1 4a 4b 5a 5b 7a 7b 8a 8b qualify - although the person has technically 9 symptoms, only 4 of them "count". How would one calculate the number of possible profiles in this case?

5) Lastly, let's move away from these 9 symptoms. Imagine you have a questionnaire with 21 questions. Each question asks: how much did you suffer from symptom x in the last 2 weeks? The scale is ordinal, from 0 (not at all) to 3 (a lot). Symptoms are simply added up to a sum-score, and my question is: how many symptom profiles exist using a certain threshold, e.g., 15? To put it differently, in how many different ways can you answer this questionnaire to achieve a sum-scores of 15 or more?

Thank you!

Comment: You might make a case for combining (1)-(4) in one question, although that's stretching it a bit, but I recommend a separate question for part (5).

Comment: Why are you trying to calculate these numbers?

Comment: Hew, I am a researcher working on covert heterogeneity in the fields of statistics and clinical psychology, and want to understand how many symptom profiles exist that all qualify for the same diagnosis. (I left question 5 in here because it always makes me uncomfortable visiting a new forum and then posting 2 questions right away; I usually only hang out on stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

(5) We want to count the number of integers solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_{21} \ge 15$$
where $0 \le x_i \le 3$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, \dots , 21$.  We can take advantage of the fact the the left hand side of the inequality cannot exceed 63 to convert it to an equivalent equality:
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_{21} + x_{22} = 63$$
where $0 \le x_{22} \le 48$. To count the solutions, we will employ a generating function.  Let's say the number of solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_{21} + x_{22} = r$$
with the above restrictions on $x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{22}$ is $a_r$, and define $f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a_r x^r$.  Then it's not very hard to see that
$$f(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3)^{21} (1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^{48})$$
so by the Binomial Theorem
$$\begin{align} 
f(x) &= \left( \frac{1-x^4}{1-x} \right)^{21} \left( \frac{1-x^{49}}{1-x} \right) \\
     & = (1-x^4)^{21} (1-x^{49}) (1-x)^{-22} \\
     & = (1-x^{49}) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{21} (-1)^i \binom{21}{i} x^{4i} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{22+j-1}{j} x^j
\end{align}$$
Examining this last expression, we can see that the coefficient of $x^{63}$ is
$$a_{63} = \sum_{i=0}^{15} (-1)^i \binom{21}{i} \binom{22+63-4i-1}{63-4i} - \sum_{i=0}^3 (-1)^i \binom{21}{i} \binom{22+14-4i-1}{14-4i}$$
which works out to be approximately $4.3966 \times 10^{12}$.

As a check on this answer, notice that the number of possibilities for $x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{21}$ is $4^{21}$, so if all the possibilities are equally likely, the probability that their sum is 15 or greater is $a_{63} / 4^{21} \approx 0.99967$.  For an independent estimate of this probability, note that if each $x_i$ is equally likely to be 0, 1, 2, or 3, then the mean of $x_i$ is $1.5$ and the variance is $1.25$.  The random variable $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{21} x_i$ then has mean $\mu = 21 \cdot 1.5 = 31.5$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 21 \cdot 1.25 = 26.25$, and by the Central Limit Theorem its distribution is approximately Normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  So $Z = (Y - \mu) / \sigma$ has a distribution which is approximately Normal(0,1).  Applying a "correction for continuity", the probability that $Y \ge 14.5$ is the probability that $Z \ge (14.5 - \mu) / \sigma \approx -3.318$, which is approximately 0.99955.  This approximate result agrees fairly well with our "exact" computation of 0.99967, so it seems the two answers are consistent.

It may occur to you that it's possible to turn this process around and deduce (approximately) the number of solutions to the original inequality from the Normal distribution, and I wouldn't blame you if you preferred this approach over the generating function method.

Comment: you may like to check this for fun: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751167/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics?lq=1 :0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer only.  I'm assuming that a symptom profile is just a set of any number of symptoms from the overall list of symptoms you're interested in.

(1) Assuming you're counting subsets of the overall 9 symptoms, you just need the number of symptoms to be at least 5.  So the answer is ${9 \choose 5} + {9 \choose 6} + ... + {9 \choose 9}$.

(2)   For list A, there are two disjoint possibilities, namely 1 or 2 of the symptoms on the list; so the total number of qualifying list A profiles is ${2 \choose 1} + {2 \choose 2}$.  Similarly the number of qualifying list B profiles is ${7 \choose 4} + ... + {7 \choose 7}$.  The two lists are independent, so the number of overall profiles is the product of those two numbers.

Comment: For (1) one could give an argument for $\binom{9}{5}+\binom{9}{6}+\binom{9}{7}+\binom{9}{8}+\binom{9}{9}$, which is $2^8$.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit for that.

Comment: thank you, i understand these. any ideas for subsequent questions? thanks again

Comment: For (3), it's not clear what you're trying to count.  I suspect this is just a lead-in to (4).  For (4), I think we'll need to know how many of the two-feature symptoms are in list A and how many are in list B.  In general, a single clear and specific problem would be more helpful.