# (Counting problem) more challenging Modular N algebraic eqs - for combinatorics-permutation experts

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Experts in algebra please help - Part II after [Part I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751167/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics): we would like to know **the number** of solutions for this set of six of modular N algebraic equations:

$$
x_1 y_2 = x_2 y_1 \pmod N \qquad (1) \\
x_1 y_3=x_3 y_1 \pmod N \qquad (2) \\
x_4 y_1 \neq x_1 y_4 \pmod N \qquad (3) \\
x_2 y_3=x_3 y_2 \pmod N \qquad (4) \\
x_2 y_4 \neq x_4 y_2 \pmod N \qquad (5) \\
x_3 y_4 \neq x_4 y_3 \pmod N \qquad (6)
$$

suppose that all variables are module $N$, i.e. $x_j=x_j \pmod N$ and $y_j=y_j \pmod N$. Here there are $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$ eight variables. NOTE: Here Eq(3),(5),(6) are required to be inequality.

> **Questions:**
>
> (a) For $N=2$, how many independent solutions there are?
>
> (b) For $N=3$, how many independent solutions there are?
>
> (c) For a generic prime number $N$, how many independent solutions there are?

I emphasize these questions about **counting number(how many) of independent solutions**, so explicit solutions for these equations are NOT required.

**Hint (what I have known):** is discussed in [Part I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751167/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics), an easier question. Here this one is less clear to me. I only know this number $\leq N^8$.

So **what is the exact number expression of this number of independent solutions**? Thank you. :o)

Comment: NOTE: Here Eq(3),(5),(6) are **required to be inequality.**

Comment: Note the use of \pmod in my edits.  MathJax is not so primitive that it can't do that.

Comment: thanks Michael for editing it. :o)

Comment: the other possibility is solving it numerically or by Mathematica. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45970/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics; but again, just like to **count the number of solutions**.